# Junit SuiteClasses with a static list of classes

Tags: java, junit4

SuiteClasses will work just fine with a list of classes like `{Test1.class,Test2.class}`, but when I try to generate a static list of classes, it says incompatible types: required `java.lang.Class<?>` but found `java.lang.Class<?>[]`

What am I missing?

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses(TestSuite.classes)
public class TestSuite {

    public static Class<?> [] classes;

    static {
       classes = new Class<?> [1];
       classes[0] = MyTest.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a space in between the <?> and the []? If so, remove that space.

Comment: The space doesn't mean anything, it's the fact that he's trying to place an array where it doesn't belong (even though the class names are listed as {M1.class,M2.class} in practice).

Answer (score 21):

That shouldn't really work. You are intended to put the array within the annotation as a constant. Even if you got past this problem, the compiler would reject it. What you need to do is this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({MyTest.class, MyOtherTest.class})
public static class TestSuite {
}
```

Note the squiggly brackets.

I'm sure what you are trying to get at is to be able to build the list of classes in the suite dynamically.

I submitted a [request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2786193&group_id=15278&atid=365278) to them to allow that, but in the mean time the only way to do it is to subclass the Suite class like so:

```
public class DynamicSuite extends Suite {

    public DynamicSuite(Class<?> setupClass) throws InitializationError {
       super(setupClass, DynamicSuiteBuilder.suite());
    }
}


@RunWith(DynamicSuite.class)
public class DynamicSuiteBuilder {
   public static Class[] suite() {
         //Generate class array here.
   }
}
```

Comment: Subclassing `Suite` helped me a lot. Unlike using `@RunWith(AllTests.class)` runner, this approach also respects `@ClassRule`s of the suite itself, as well as classes it contains.

Comment: I tried this approach to implement setUp and tearDown. But the DynamicSuite constructor is getting called before @ beforeclass.  Is there any way @ beforeclass can be called before constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`@SuiteClasses` is a class annotation defined in JUnit 4.4 in org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses. It allows you to define a suite class as described in the previous question.

By the way, the API document of JUnit 4.4 has a major typo for the org.junit.runners.Suite class (Suite.html).

Using Suite as a runner allows you to manually build a suite containing tests from many classes. It is the JUnit 4 equivalent of the JUnit 3.8.x static Test `suite()` method. To use it, annotate a class with `@RunWith(Suite.class)` and `@SuiteClasses(TestClass1.class, ...)`. When you run this class, it will run all the tests in all the suite classes.

`@SuiteClasses(TestClass1.class, ...)` should be changed to `@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, ...})`.

Someone provided wrong information on build test suite in JUnit 4.4. Do not follow this:

JUnit provides tools to define the suite to be run and to display its results. To run tests and see the results on the console, run:

```
org.junit.runner.TextListener.run(TestClass1.class, ...);
```