# Creating TestSuite for Junit TestMethods from Multiple UnitTest Classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a scenario in which there are multiple Unit Test classes which is run independently each one having all the setUp(), tearDown(), and testMethod(). 
Each class extends junit.framework.TestCase . Is there way to create a single suite to run all the testMethods from all the UnitTestClasses.

Note: I know how to create a suite with multiple Testmethods from same class. 
Version: Junit 4.8

Can anyone suggest me how to do the same for testMethods from different classes ?

Comment: If you use Junit 4.x, why use `extends TestCase` at all? A `@Test` annotation is enough to make a method a test method IIRC

Comment: If I don't use eclipse does show the option 'Run As JunitTest', I m not sure if that is for any other reason.

Comment: How are you running your tests - eclipse, ant, maven?

Comment: Through Eclipse, Right click on the Class or particular TestMethod and  Run As -> JUnit Test

Comment: See also this Stackoverflow question on [Junit SuiteClasses with a static list of classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070202/junit-suiteclasses-with-a-static-list-of-classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JUnit way would be

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({MyTest.class, MyOtherTest.class})
```

Note that suites can be nested, so `MyTest` could also be a suite.

In this way you'd have, e.g., a suite per package, which you then in turn can group into the overall test suite.

I'm not aware of a JUnit class simply collecting all test classes in a package/folder: that functionality is provided by `ant`, `maven`, or `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

I migth not have understood you correctly, but I think what you are looking for is to run a "package"-test something like this

```
<test name="Unittests">
        <packages>
            <package name="mypackage.tests"></package>
        </packages></test>
</suite>
```