# Adding Test to TestSuite in JUnit4

Tags: java, junit

Is there a way to programmatically add test to a testsuite in JUnit4?

In Junit3 you can do this

```
TestSuite ts = new TestSuite();
ts.addTestSuite(a.class);
ts.addTestSuite(b.class);
```

How bout in JUnit4?

Comment: found this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070568/485978 but im not to sure how to run it.

Comment: ok got it, create a new test suite with @SuiteClasses ({Dynamic*.class})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Request#classes()](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Request.html#classes%28java.lang.Class...%29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Request request = Request.classes(new Class<?>[] {Test1.class, Test2.class});

    JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
    RunListener listener = new RunListener() {

        @Override
        public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("failure=" + failure);
        }

    };
    jUnitCore.addListener(listener);
    jUnitCore.run(request);
}
```

In the RunListener, you can override more than just testFailure.

If you want your tests to be more integrated into your build, then extend Suite

```
public static class DynamicSuite extends Suite {
    public DynamicSuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
        super(builder, klass, new Class<?>[] {Test1.class, Test2.class});
    }
}
```

The constructor that you use depends upon how the Suite is invoked. The above works in Eclipse.

Then just annotate an empty class with `@RunWith(DynamicSuite.class)`:

```
@RunWith(DynamicSuite.class)
public class DynamicTestSuite {
}
```